# com.mysql.jdbc.exception.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: No operation allowed after connection closed

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

how to solve this problem and what is wrong in this code?
i know that the question has been asked before but i cant solve the problem

```
private void cb_categoriesPopupMenuWillBecomeVisible(javax.swing.event.PopupMenuEvent evt) {                                                         
     cb_categories.removeAllItems();
    try {
        String sql_c = "SELECT * FROM inventory.categories";
        cc.pst = cc.c.prepareStatement(sql_c);
        cc.rs = cc.pst.executeQuery();
        while (cc.rs.next()) {
            String c_name = cc.rs.getString("CategoryName");
            cb_categories.addItem(c_name);

        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    } finally {
        try {
            cc.rs.close();
            cc.pst.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Whats the problem exactly? Whats the output and whats your desired result?

Comment: when combobox become visible it displays a list from database

Comment: Edit your question since your question is not clear for me!

Comment: when combobox is clicked  it displays a list from database.. i did that many times in other apps but this time it gives me that error why?

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45784304/java-sql-sqlexception-operation-not-allowed-after-resultset-closed-java-mysql

Answer (score 1):

Your ResultSet and PreparedStatement are not declared in method scope, so I have to assume that you've declared them elsewhere.

That's a big mistake.

You should declare the Statement and ResultSet in method scope.

You make an attempt to close your resources, but you should wrap them in individual try/catch blocks.  You cannot risk one being closed and not the other.

There are other things I'd criticize about your code (e.g. SELECT *, mingling UI and database code together in a single class), but that's enough to start.

Start with an interface:

```
package persistence;

import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by Michael
 * Creation date 8/20/2017.
 * @link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45787151/com-mysql-jdbc-exception-jdbc4-mysqlnontransientconnectionexception-no-operatio/45787321?noredirect=1#comment78532554_45787321
 */
public interface CategoryDao {
    List<String> findAllCategories();
}
```

Then write a concrete implementation:

```
package database;

import database.util.DatabaseUtils;
import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;

import javax.sql.DataSource;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by Michael
 * Creation date 8/20/2017.
 * @link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45787151/com-mysql-jdbc-exception-jdbc4-mysqlnontransientconnectionexception-no-operatio/45787321?noredirect=1#comment78532554_45787321
 */
public class CategoryDaoImpl implements CategoryDao {

    private static final Log LOGGER = LogFactory.getLog(CategoryDaoImpl.class);
    private static String SELECT_CATEGORIES = "SELECT CategoryName from inventory.Categories ";

    private DataSource dataSource;

    public CategoryDaoImpl(DataSource dataSource) {
        this.dataSource = dataSource;
    }

    @Override
    public List<String> findAllCategories() {
        List<String> categories = new ArrayList<>();
        PreparedStatement ps = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        try {
            ps = this.dataSource.getConnection().prepareStatement(SELECT_CATEGORIES);
            rs = ps.executeQuery();
            while (rs.next()) {
                categories.add(rs.getString("CategoryName"));
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            LOGGER.error(String.format("Exception caught while selecting all category names"), e);
        } finally {
            DatabaseUtils.close(rs);
            DatabaseUtils.close(ps);
        }
        return categories;
    }
}
```

This is something that you can test with JUnit off to the side.  Get it running perfectly, then give a reference to your UI code.  It'll keep the UI and database code separate.  You can use this DAO in any application without worrying about Swing or web UI.

Comment: +1 Also `cc` which is instance of connection is being closed and reused again in closed state (from the view of code shared). I suggest to use CollectionPooling mechanism

Comment: Yes, the connection should be passed into the separate data access class that you should create and test on its own.  Give your controller an instance of that interface based class and call its methods.